# CSS not working in a dynamically created page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am new to JQuery Mobile and trying to build a simple app. Part of the codes as follows:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".trycss").css({
            'background': 'red' });
    $.post("http://getcheckout.php", 
        function(data){
            var CheckOutListHTML ='<p class="trycss"> HELLO</p>';
                $('.class-ItemsList').append(CheckOutListHTML);
            },"json");
    });

</script>

<div data-role="page" id="id-ItemsPage">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Items</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">   
        <div class="class-ItemsList">
        </div>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

So, I am trying to use the "trycss" to style something I am creating dynamically. But it is not working. Can someone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try following:**

```
 <style>
   .trycss { background-color: red; }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("http://getcheckout.php", 
        function(data){
            var CheckOutListHTML ='<p class="trycss"> HELLO</p>';
                $('.class-ItemsList').append(CheckOutListHTML);
            },"json");
    });

</script>

<div data-role="page" id="id-ItemsPage">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Items</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">   
        <div class="class-ItemsList">
        </div>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(".trycss").css(...` is executed once and applies styles (not "a style sheet") to all matching elements that exist at that point of time ans you don't you create your element until later on.

What exactly are you attempting to do? Why are you using `$(".trycss").css(...` and not a style sheet like @hardik suggests?

Comment: Yes, I should be using style sheet I guess. I am new to these stuff and is just trying different things out for my app.